# Python: WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available

Tags: python, pip, openssl, windows-7

Windows 7, python 3.8.5 64bit, I'm trying to run a venv, it works great on my windows 7 desktop but I just cant get the SSL working on my laptop. I went through literally every post about this on this site and I'm still befuddled.

"WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available."

that is what happens when I pip install talib or openssl. Then it tells me to upgrade my PIP, so I enter the command and the prompt changes to >>, and I can't get back to the normal prompt without restarting VSCode. I tried youtube tutorials as well as this site and google and I am stumped, any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try installing pyopenssl. pip install pyopenssl. It should fix your issues.

It is required to have OpenSSL to install pyopenssl. Download from here: https://www.openssl.org/source/

Comment: `pip install pyopenssl` doesn't work because `pip` requires OpenSSL to be installed.

Comment: This was an interesting suggestion, I tried installing pyopenssl butt it did not work due to the above error of not being able to use TLS/SSL

Comment: Download OpenSSL here: https://www.openssl.org/source/

Comment: I went to this site and installed using Git Bash, and it worked! Not sure if the other things I did helped or not, but this was the correct final step. Thank you!

Comment: No problem, I'm glad this helped you!

Comment: These warnings don't mean your program isn't working by the way, and they aren't errors.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Control Panel's Programs > Programs and Features, look for Python, click then select "Change" then choose to Modify to add or remove individual features. Check all the boxes then click next to proceed to Advanced Options, from then, check the  2, 3 and 4 boxes then install.

Comment: thank you for your response but unfortunately all of those boxes were already checked. I went through the process anyway just to be sure, but it did not work.

Comment: it actually didn't work, still not recognizing the SSL certificate :(

Comment: @WillPowers Aw, I'm so sorry to hear that but that was the thing I did in my part.